# .Java error(content size increases)

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am using LWUIT in j2me.  There is only one .java file containing midlet and 10 images consisting total size of 49kb.

I had added LWUIT.jar in resource file.
Now my application executes and rusn properly in simulater  .But when I install it in device it is showing me this error:

> ```
> .java error content size to large
> ```

As the .jar file is of size 556KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Obfuscating to high level and reduce the Jar file size. Also see this article, [Jar size Optimization.](http://www.j2mesalsa.com/articles/JarSize.html)

If you are using NetBeans means follow these steps,

1. Right click the project and go to properties.
2. Select Obfuscating in Build and set into High level.
3. Clean and Build the project and see your Jar file size.

Comment: Also, [this](http://home.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/java-error-content-size-too-large) may help, though it's old.